Prove that $Hom_{R_S}(R_S,A) \otimes_{R_S} N ≅ Hom_R(R_S, A \otimes_R N).$
If $A$ is an Artinian $R$-module, $N$ a finitely presented $R$-module and $S$ is a multiplicative set in $R$, then there is a natural isomorphism
$Hom_{R_S}(R_S,A) \otimes_{R_S} N \to Hom_R(R_S, A \otimes_R N).$
With each R-module $X$,  I have proved that there exists a natural homomorphism between $Hom_{R_S}(R_S,A) \otimes_{R_S} X$ and $Hom_R(R_S, A \otimes_R X)$, but I don't know how to prove they are isomorphic.

Something is off here. (1) Why do you write $\hom_{R_S}(R_S,A)$, as this is always just $A$? (2) How do you form the tensor product over $R_S$ on the left side, maybe $A$ and $N$ are actually $R_S$-modules? (3) Is $R$ commutative, or does $S$ satisfy the Ore-condition? Please clarify these points.
